# Htacces rewrite rules and conditions

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have this rule which works perfectly

> RewriteEngine on
>   RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)    /demo/index.php?**category**=$1&**subcategory**=$2

this converts my link from

> /demo/index.php?**category**=ABC&**subcategory**=XYZ
>   to
>   /demo/ABC/XYZ

but at times I want to enter just the category name like this

> /demo/ABC/

But unfortunately this gives error **Page not found**. What causes this error and how can I fix it?

*Also can someone provide link to RewriteEngine resources/books/tutorials. I couldn't find anything that would help a beginner like me. Thank you.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your rule to:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]*) /demo/index.php?category=$1&subcategory=$2 [L,QSA]
```

This making second argument optional (using `*` instead of `+` in `[^/]*`)

Comment: I made further changes to the rule as it was giving me errors when I wrote the URL without a forward slash like this

----

`/demo/ABC`

----


So I changed the rule to have 3 arguements and 2nd arguement being the forward slash and made it optional using * as you mentioned.

----

`RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(/*)([^/]*) /demo/index.php?category=$1&subcategory=$3 [L,QSA]`

----

It works now but is it the right approach?

Comment: Better to use it this way: `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?([^/]*) /demo/index.php?category=$1&subcategory=$3 [L,QSA]`

Comment: Thanks again Sir, where can I find all this information so that even I can learn it and not bother you much :)

Comment: You're welcome. I usually refer to: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html but this does have some learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

Unless `/demo/ABC/` is a directory that exists on your local file system, it won't be able to find the page. Your first rule is only rewriting that parameter-filled link into that pseduo-path, it doesn't establish a virtual directory or create a solid redirect.

The best info for `RewriteRule` is probably going to be in the actual [Apache docs.](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)